# How to fill the missing values in an array with another array

Tags: javascript

How to fill the missing values in the array1

```
array1 = [1,'',12,23,'',5]
```

basically, they are 3 values but only 2 values can be placed

```
array2 = [6,8,9]
```

sample output

```
array1 = [1,6,12,23,8,5]
array2 = [9]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mre] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Just a side note: Those aren't missing values, they're strings. I mention this because JavaScript arrays can actually have *missing* values because they can be [sparse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix). You could create that array with actually missing values by doing this: `const array1 = []; array1[0] = 1; array1[2] = 12; array[3] = 23; array1[5] = 5;` or slightly more obscurely: `const array1 = Object.assign([], {0: 1, 2: 12, 3: 23, 5: 5});`

Comment: @t-j-crowder this is noted. Next time I'll include my attempts in my questions. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with something like this.

```
array1 = [1,'',12,23,'',5]
array2 = [6,8,9]
array1 = array1.map(val => val === '' ? array2.shift() : val);
```

Or

```
for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  if (array1[i] === '') array1[i] = array2.shift();
}
```

Read about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

```
let array1 = [1,'',12,23,'',5]
let array2 = [6,8,9]
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if(array1[i]=== ''){
        console.log(array1[i])
         array1[i] = array2.shift()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array1 = [1,'',12,23,'',5];
const array2 = [6,8,9];

array1 = array1.map((item) => {
    if (Boolean(item)) {
        return item
    } else {
        return array2.shift();
    }
});

console.log(array1);
console.log(array2);
```